# Should we change the "kismet" tag to "udk-kismet?"

Tags: discussion, tags

I have noticed that the [kismet](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kismet) has started to become more popular. It is a component of the free UDK engine, so wouldn't it be better as something such as [udk-kismet](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/udk-kismet)?

Or is it better if a component is separately labeled?

Answer (score 4):

The term "kismet" doesn't have any other common meaning in the context of game development, so I don't think there is any danger of ambiguity. Further, I would expect that "kismet" is more discoverable and expected as a tag name than anything prefixed (or suffixed) with "udk."

I don't see a reason to change the tag.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, in the context of game development, Kismet is very specific to UDK (UE4 has Blueprint) so without the term being ambiguous I don't see a need to change the tag to be more explicit.

Comment: As a side note, it is perfectly fine for a question to be tagged with both Kismet and UDK